# check result null mysql

Tags: php, mysql

this below mysql command is return null result.

how to check this in php

```
SELECT (sum(`money1`) - sum(`money2`)) as sm FROM `manfeatokasb`
```

below code is not correct and could not check null results

```
if ($result['sm'] === null  )
{
    echo 'this command is return null result';
}
```

Comment: Not enough code.  Please post how you execute the query and fetch into `$result`.

Answer (score 1):

Use [`is_null()`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.is-null.php)

```
if (is_null($result['sm']))
{
    echo 'this command is return null result';
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use mysql_num_rows

```
if(mysql_num_rows($result) != 0){
     //code if "not null"
}else{
    //code if "null"
}
```